# HTML file upload with jQuery/Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to incorporate some code from Stack user DannYo's [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/362136), however my version of his code doesn't seem to run. The error and the "beforesend" functions return each time.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <input type="email" id="sender" name="sender" required>
    <input type="email" id="receiver" name="receiver" required>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
    <button id="send" class="button">Send it</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {

    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr

            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

            if (myXhr.upload) { // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }

            return myXhr;

        },

        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: function() { console.log("before send function works"); },
        success: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        error: function() { console.log("error function works"); },

        // Form data
        data: formData,

        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;

});
```

**PHP**

For testing purposes, the `upload.php` file only has `<?php echo "success"; ?>`

Using Chrome's network developer tool, I don't see my file being transferred anywhere. Anybody see a glaring hole in my code? Thanks

Comment: `The error and the "beforesend" functions return each time.` What error are you given?

Comment: Console log just prints what I specified in the error function: "error function works"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your error function is being called, then the answer is most likely within its result. Please check what error is being returned as displaying `error function works` does you no good.

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    // OR
    alert(status + " : " + error);
}
```

**Edit**: Also to note, I believe you need to handle the saving of file that you are trying to upload. T[his tutorial for uploading files in php](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php/) may be useful.

Comment: I agree my error function is silly. Using the one you gave me, it just refreshes the page but not before displaying this in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot ready property 'Message' of undefined`

Comment: @muppethead Thats interesting. I have updated my answer with something else I have done before.

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, your edit proved helpful. The error said `progressHandlingFunction` was not defined. So, I added the progress handling function and now the form doesn't return the error function. But instead I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Is that because I'm working locally with MAMP?

Comment: Actually, forget that. My php file had badly commented out text that caused the 500 ISE. Everything now works as it should. Thanks for your help Josh